# Equivalent to UserSettings / ApplicationSettings in WPF for newer .NET versions

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0, .net-5, .net-7.0

What is the prefered way for **persisting user settings** for WPF applications with [.net-5](/questions/tagged/.net-5) , [.net-6.0](/questions/tagged/.net-6.0), [.net-7.0](/questions/tagged/.net-7.0) or [.net-core](/questions/tagged/.net-core)>=3.0?
Where are the .NET user settings gone?

Created WPF .Net Core 3.0 Project (VS2019 V16.3.1)
Now I have seen there is no **Properties.Settings** section anymore.

[**Update 2022**: With .NET 6 it is still the same]
[**Update 2023**: With .NET 7 it is still the same]

[image: SolutionExplorer]

After online search, started to dive into Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.

Beside the bloated code to access the settings, now even worse -> No save?
[User Configuration Settings in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51351464/3090544)

> Fortunately or unfortunately the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
> does not support saving by design. Read more in this Github issue [Why
> there is no save in ConfigurationProvider?](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/385)

What is the prefered (and easy/fast/simple) way for persisting user settings for WPF applications with .Net Core >=3.0 / .NET5 / .NET6 / .NET7?

Before <= .Net 4.8 it was as easy as:

- add the variables to the Properties.
  [image: User Settings]
- Read the variables at startup
  `var culture = new CultureInfo(Properties.Settings.Default.LanguageSettings);`
- when a variable changes -> immediately save it
  `Properties.Settings.Default.LanguageSettings = selected.TwoLetterISOLanguageName; Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`

Comment: I'm curious, what has lead you to want to mutate your configuration files at runtime? What prompts these changes? Are you trying to use your config as some kind of user profile?

Comment: I'm talking about the settings to improve user convenience. In my example above it seems like application settings, but I like to allow users to select their language. And why should I force my users to edit a config file? Why shouldn't provide an admin area to let it configure? Why shouldn't do it like [How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp) I'm using/saving successfully these user settings since about 15 years. Should we go back to the registry? Back to the roots?

Comment: I have no "answer" right now. But I would expect there to be some kind of configuration abstraction that would write either to LocalApplicationData, ApplicationData or CommonApplicationData, depending on the scope of the user settings. I would expect this abstraction to forbid you to change the application level config of your app (for many reasons, including that your permissions levels are likely to be inadequate). This is what I'd expect from Microsoft's configuration code *for client apps*. The documentation you've linked is asp.net documentation, which is completely different.

Comment: I assumed that Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration is the way to go even for WPF/WinForms <-> .Net Core not only ASP.Net. I haven't found yet any other information.

Comment: One _reference_ where I read that Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration should be used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48866609/3090544

Comment: Ahhh, I may have been wrong when I said that was asp.net only then. I hope someone who knows answers. In the meantime the way I'd tackle it might be to just serial a file in LocalApplicationData and just ignore the microsoft config stuff.

Comment: I had similar frustrations. I just went with JSON.net in the end. Super simple

Comment: You can always use a simple plain text file (JSON, XML, plain _key=value;key=value_, or ini-file-formatting if you need sections) or lightweight database like SQLite. You can also create plain data objects and serialize them. Setting this up (maybe except SQLite and serialization) is done very quickly. XML and JSON (via API) can modify and search the data without explicit parsing. XML allows simple and easy traversal (e.g. LINQ to XML).

Comment: So we are back to "just roll your own (crappy) solution" for the most basic of things. I thought we had left that behind some 20 years ago.

Comment: If I roll my own JSON file, where am I supposed to save it?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

[image]

You can add the same old good settings file e.g. via the right click on the Properties -> Add -> New Item and search for the "Settings". The file can be edited in the settings designer and used as in the .net framework projects before (ConfigurationManager, Settings.Default.Upgrade(), Settings.Default.Save, etc. works).

Add also the app.config file to the project root folder (the same way via the Add -> New Item), save the settings once again, compile the project and you will find a .dll.config file in the output folder. You can change now default app values as before.

Tested with Visual Studio 1.16.3.5 and a .net core 3.0 WPF project.

Comment: Could be so easy! This should be the answer with bounty... Tested with VS2019 V16.3.6

Comment: And where is the <exe-file>.config to be editied when deploying? Or are they renamed/relocated? Before .Net Core settings we had our config to be editied in the same directory as the exe file.

Comment: This is replaced now by <executable..dll.config> file.
Can I get the bounty, please?

Comment: To my knowledge a change of the bounty assignment isn't possible, but I changed the accepted answer to yours. Include at least 15 points... :-)

Comment: In my WPF Core 3.1 project, the solution explorer looks like in the question, not like in the answer. There are no Properties, meaning I also cannot right click them.

Comment: You also have to install the NuGet Package `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`

Comment: @PeterHuber if you can't find the Properties folder, just create them, and later add a .settings file to it

Comment: Works perfect. But I get a lot of IntelliSense Messages in the Error List. "Could not find schema information for the element 'userSetting' ", "Could not find schema information for the element 'setting' ", and so on.

Comment: Subsequent additions to the Settings file in the UI followed by Save gives error dialog: An Error occurred while save saving values to the app.config file. The file might be corrupted or contain invalid XML.  I'm using .net core 3.0 in console app

Comment: After adding app.config, how do I save..? Also, app.settings does not support a usersettings tag anymore. How does the data from Settings get into the app.config file.

Comment: Thanks. Automatically creates <myproject>.dll.config from App.Config which can be modified externally. Unfortunately it fails when creating a single exe. Any suggestions?

Comment: @PeterHuber my project, initially, didnt include the Properties folder.  i had to create a Publish profile which created the properties folder with the publish profile under it.  then Settings were then add as the answer suggested.

Comment: Where is the user.config saved on the user's machine now?

Answer (score 33):

As pointed out in the posts you referenced, the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration API is meant as a one time set up for your app, or at the very least to be read-only. If you're main goal is to persist user settings easy/fast/simple, you could roll something up yourself. Storing the settings in the `ApplicationData` folder, in resemblance to the old API.

```cs
public class SettingsManager<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly string _filePath;

    public SettingsManager(string fileName)
    {
        _filePath = GetLocalFilePath(fileName);
    }

    private string GetLocalFilePath(string fileName)
    {
        string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        return Path.Combine(appData, fileName);
    }

    public T LoadSettings() =>
        File.Exists(_filePath) ?
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(File.ReadAllText(_filePath)) :
        null;

    public void SaveSettings(T settings)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings);
        File.WriteAllText(_filePath, json);
    }
}
```

---

A demo using the most basic of `UserSettings`

```cs
public class UserSettings
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not going to provide a full MVVM example, still we'd have an instance in memory, ref `_userSettings`. Once you load settings, the demo will have its default properties overridden. In production, of course, you wouldn't provide default values on start up. It's just for the purpose of illustration.

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly SettingsManager<UserSettings> _settingsManager;
    private UserSettings _userSettings;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _userSettings = new UserSettings() { Name = "Funk" };
        _settingsManager = new SettingsManager<UserSettings>("UserSettings.json");
    }

    private void Button_FromMemory(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Apply(_userSettings);
    }

    private void Button_LoadSettings(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _userSettings = _settingsManager.LoadSettings();
        Apply(_userSettings);
    }

    private void Button_SaveSettings(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _userSettings.Name = textBox.Text;
        _settingsManager.SaveSettings(_userSettings);
    }

    private void Apply(UserSettings userSettings)
    {
        textBox.Text = userSettings?.Name ?? "No settings found";
    }
}
```

XAML

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        </Style> 
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="textBox" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_FromMemory">From Memory</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Click="Button_LoadSettings">Load Settings</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Click="Button_SaveSettings">Save Settings</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Suggest switch to System.Text.Json rather than newtonsoft

Comment: This is the better solution! Using the "old" Settings-Approach in combination with MSIX results in your Application-Settings getting overwritten on every auto-update.

Comment: The Property.Settings api had a save method. it was not readonly. It was awesome and super easy to use to store and load users settings in the local appdata, where settings like that belog. It was TYPE SAFE without relying on crappy string stuff like settings["LeftHotkey"].

Comment: @Blechdose Have you even read OP, we were talking about Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, which doesn't have a save method. My proposed solution is both type safe and saves settings in local appdata, or anywhere you'd like.

Comment: @Funk OP post is about Property.Settings which he is missing in .NET Core and you said "The Configuration API" which then refers to Property.Settings. Though you are right, i missed the "posts you reference" part (you mean links?). But it is still confusing. Could you please edit it to "Configuration API" to "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration"?

Comment: How in the hell is this progress? Going from a well-working and established system for storing user-settings, that was easy to use and integrated into the IDE to "oh well just cook your own, store it in a txt file somewhere or something". This whole .net core project is such a massive step back from the .NET Framework, it is truly mind-boggling.

Answer (score 14):

You can use a Nuget package [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/). It is compatible with .Net Standard 2.0, so it should be usable in .Net Core application.

There is no designer for this, but otherwise it works the same as .Net version, and you should be able to just copy the code from your `Settings.Designer.cs`. Also, you can override `OnPropertyChanged`, so there's no need to call `Save`.

Here's an example, from the working .Net Standard project:

```
public class WatchConfig: ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    static WatchConfig _defaultInstance = (WatchConfig)Synchronized(new WatchConfig());

    public static WatchConfig Default { get => _defaultInstance; }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Save();
        base.OnPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    }

    [UserScopedSetting]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute(
    @"<?xml    version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?>
    <ArrayOfString>
      <string>C:\temp</string>
     <string>..\otherdir</string>
     </ArrayOfString>")]
    public StringCollection Directories
    {
        get { return (StringCollection)this[nameof(Directories)]; }
        set { this[nameof(Directories)] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: For me it seems to be the current simplest replacement for the missing user settings. It will keep the saving scheme in ApplicationData like it was before you don't need to create a app.config.  Successfully tested with VS 2019 Preview 16.2.0 Preview 3.0 and .Net Core SDK 3.0.0-preview6-27804 and Nuget package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 4.6.0-preview6.199303.8

Comment: It is just to add this 'custom-settings-class' to your project where you have to add the settings variables as properties with some annotations where you could watch how it should look like in other old `Settings.Designer.cs`.

Answer (score 14):

My improvements to the accepted answer were rejected, so here as separate answer.

**There is no need for any nuget package and no need to roll your own JSON etc.**
By default when creating new .NET Core or .NET5/6/7 projects the settings section is missing and you have to manually add it.

**<Update 2023>**

As described by Viacheslav there is a solution with almost just one button click. Open project properties, go to Setting and just click on the link "Create or open application settings". 
Tested with VS 2022 and [.net7](/questions/tagged/.net7)

[image: Settings in project properties]

The described old manual method is kept under this update. 
**</Update 2023>**

Just manually create the Properties folder in the solution.
As you name the new folder `Properties` you will see that the folder icon will change slightly.

[image: Properties folder]

Right click on this new Properties folder and add New Item

Add a Settings File and to be same as in old projects rename the proposed name from `Settings1.settings` to `Settings.settings`

[image: Add Settings File]

Here you are. Settings are back already.

[image: Settings dialog]

You  might add an Application Configuration File to get the .config file in the output directory

[image: Add Application Configuration File]

Answer (score 8):

Based on Funk's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56961180/521443) here's an abstract generic singleton-style variation that removes some of the administration around SettingsManager and makes creating additional settings classes and using them as simple as possible:

Typed Settings class:

```cs
//Use System.Text.Json attributes to control serialization and defaults
public class MySettings : SettingsManager<MySettings>
{
    public bool SomeBoolean { get; set; }
    public string MyText { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
//Loading and reading values
MySettings.Load();
var theText = MySettings.Instance.MyText;
var theBool = MySettings.Instance.SomeBoolean;

//Updating values
MySettings.Instance.MyText = "SomeNewText"
MySettings.Save();
```

As you can see the number of lines to create and use your settings are just as minimal, and a bit more rigid as there are no parameters.

The base class defines where settings are stored and allows only for one settings file per MySettings subclass - assembly and class names determine its location. For the purpose of replacing a properties file that is enough.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public abstract class SettingsManager<T> where T : SettingsManager<T>, new()
{
    private static readonly string filePath = GetLocalFilePath($"{typeof(T).Name}.json");

    public static T Instance { get; private set; }

    private static string GetLocalFilePath(string fileName)
    {
        string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData); 
        var companyName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttributes<AssemblyCompanyAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        return Path.Combine(appData, companyName?.Company ?? Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name, fileName);
    }

    public static void Load()
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
            Instance = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
        else
            Instance = new T(); 
    }

    public static void Save()
    {
        string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Instance);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);
    }
}
```

Some improvements might be made in disabling the constructor of the settings subclass and creation of `SettingsManager<T>.Instance` without Load()ing it; that depends on your own use cases.

Answer (score 7):

**For Wpf Net.Core**

**Project** click Right Mouse Button -> Add New Item -> Settings File (General)

Use

```
Settings1.Default.Height = this.Height;
Settings1.Default.Width = this.Width;

this.Height = Settings1.Default.Height;
this.Width = Settings1.Default.Width;

Settings1.Default.Save();
```

Where 'Settings1' created file name

*EXAMPLE*

Double click '**Settings1.settings**' file and Edit

```
private void MainWindowRoot_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Top = Settings1.Default.Top;
    this.Left = Settings1.Default.Left;
    this.Height = Settings1.Default.Height;
    this.Width = Settings1.Default.Width;
    // Very quick and dirty - but it does the job
    if (Settings1.Default.Maximized)
    {
        WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
}

private void MainWindowRoot_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
    {
        // Use the RestoreBounds as the current values will be 0, 0 and the size of the screen
        Settings1.Default.Top = RestoreBounds.Top;
        Settings1.Default.Left = RestoreBounds.Left;
        Settings1.Default.Height = RestoreBounds.Height;
        Settings1.Default.Width = RestoreBounds.Width;
        Settings1.Default.Maximized = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Settings1.Default.Top = this.Top;
        Settings1.Default.Left = this.Left;
        Settings1.Default.Height = this.Height;
        Settings1.Default.Width = this.Width;
        Settings1.Default.Maximized = false;
    }

    Settings1.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: interesting, it works in WPF, (Net Core 3.1) but not in a console app (Net Core 3.1). The console app version simply does not have the .Save() method

Comment: @Welcor My .NET console app had no save method until I installed "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" NuGet package. Then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Just a button click

Project => Properties -> Resources

[image: Project Resources Settings]

Comment: Your screenshot only depicts to create/open assembly resources. You should have included the "Settings" section at the bottom for the screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

Just double click the `Settings.settings` file in your project. It will still open up in the designer just like before. You just do not have it listed in Properties windows anymore.

Comment: And where could I find this settings file? There is no such file in a solution for a WPF .Net Core App, even not on folder level. Just tested again with a newly created project with VS2019 V16.3.3

Comment: "Settings File" is in the list of file types when you right-click the project and select _Add New Item_. However, it's a read-only settings file because there's no _Save()_ method. (You also can't call _Upgrade()_ or _Reload()_, so you can't move settings from an old version to a new one.)