# WPF C# Properties.Settings doesn't exist

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, settings

I'm trying to create simple application/user settings for my WPF application.

Most answers and tutorials suggest using `Properties.Settings.Default` for this.
However, `Settings` doesn't exist in my `Properties` namespace.
There is also no **.settings** file in my project explorer, as [the microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-a-new-setting-at-design-time) suggests:

> 1. Open Visual Studio.
> 2. In **Solution Explorer**, expand the **Properties** node of your project.
> 3. Double-click the **.settings** file in which you want to add a new setting. The default name for this file is Settings.settings.

[image: Solution explorer]

Also there is no **Settings** tab in my project properties window, as some (older?) resources suggest.

[image: Project properties window]

Comment: did you tried add new `.settings` file ? ... are you using .NET Framework or Core?

Comment: This really seems like a duplicate question, since the accepted answer just links to another question's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58423458/10703868

Looks like you are using .NET Core instead of .NET Framework with WPF. Right click on your `MyApp` Project and add a new folder titled "Properties". Then right click on that and add a new item. Search for settings, add the settings file. They you should be able to use this.

[image]

I don't see the settings tab in my project properties view, but if you right click on the settings file you can change the `Open with` to be the settings designer for the old view.

Comment: So it was that simple. Thanks a lot! How come I couldn't find an answer in the Microsoft documentation? It's not really obvious from my point of view

Comment: Yeah, it can be a little tough to keep track of .NET Core and Foundation documentation and answers. I had a lot of issues with EF 6 vs EF Core. I've started paying closer attention to the names and versions as well as the date.

Answer (score 1):

WPF App (.NET Core) template doesn't seem to be adding .settings file by default, as opposed to WPF App (.NET Framework).

You can add it by right clicking your project file -> Add -> New Item... -> Settings File (you can search for it, or browse for it under Visual C# -> General).